# Manipulation of Time in VC++

Tags: windows, time, visual-c++

how to calculate the starting and end time of switch in VC++ can anyone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [clock() function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/)

```
#include <time.h>

clock_t start = clock();
//...
//do something
double total = (double) (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

here the total variable holds the time (in seconds) the do something part takes to complete.

Note that if you need more accurate timing you can use [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905(VS.85).aspx) functions, however they specific to Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to calculate how long the switch took to execute try calling gettickcount before and then after and subtract the two values should give you the delay in milliseconds.